# Microsoft Graph subscriptions for user changes only for password change

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, subscription

I want to create a user subscription for password changes.
I got the 'updated' subscription, but it triggers for 'every' user change. Is there a way to determine what actually changed for this notification?

The data I get from the subscription is:

```
jsonPayload: {
value: [
0: {
changeType: "updated"
clientState: "743BYRLbv7Jxxxxxx:xxxxxxDSCHig39uKvoSwI7V9wg=="
resource: "Users/8d5xxxxxxc3e8c2dbeec"
resourceData: {
@odata.id: "Users/8d517xxxxxxx5c3e8c2dbeec"
@odata.type: "#Microsoft.Graph.User"
id: "8d51xxxxxd-5c3e8c2dbeec"
organizationId: "4d85xxxxxx-8a38-9e8e05cdd5d4"
}
subscriptionExpirationDateTime: "2023-10-04T06:42:00.345-07:00"
subscriptionId: "916xxxxx-a2a6-0d5d06c98f55"
tenantId: "4xxxxx38-9e8e05cdd5d4"
}]}
```